# Cassanda: create a supercolumn with standard columns inside

Tags: cassandra

Im trying to create a supercolumn family with 2 columns families inside.

I know how to create the column families but how do i associate them to the supercolumn?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SuperColumns contain columns, not ColumnFamilies.  But SuperColumns are not what you want to use, either way.  See http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1 and possibly http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3_collections as well.